# Max number of X digits number

Tags: c++, numbers, max

I am looking for an idea about a condition that stop when an integer reach to the max number of its digit..

i.e

the max number of 2 digits number is 99

the max number of 5 digits number is 99999

I got this one

```
while(x != ([10^number of digits] -1))
{
    x++;
}
cout << x;
```

but actually i am dealing with string, which may i have a huge numbers, and this code start to get very long execution time after 9 digits.

So can any one give me a good idea about that, Thanks.

Comment: What programming language ? Please use appropriate tags.

Comment: I am using c++ ..srry :)

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish?  Do you just want to obtain a number that is N 9s?  If so, that's easy.  At any rate, an easy improvement to the code you have there would be to compute `10^number of digits - 1` before your loop and not during the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
done = false;
while(!done)
{
    x++;
    done = true;
    for (i=0 ; i<number_of_digits; i++)
       if x[i] != '9'
          done = false;
}
cout << x;
```

Comment: This is what I was I wanted, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It would be a bit faster to use

```
x = ([10^number of digits] -1);
```

instead of

```
while(x != ([10^number of digits] -1))
{
    x++;
}
```