# Get min and max integer value containing X number of digits

Tags: c#, math, numbers, number-formatting

What would be the best way to generate the lowest and highest integer values which contain `x` number of digits?

For example:

- `x` = 1: Min = 0, Max = 9
- `x` = 2: Min = 10, Max = 99
- `x` = 3: Min = 100, Max = 999
- `x` = 4: Min = 1000, Max = 9999

I feel like this should be a really easy thing to accomplish but I'm struggling to get my head around the math behind it.

Here's what I've got so far for generating the **max** value ([based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14423292/6236042)):

```
public static int MaxIntWithXDigits(this int x)
{
    if (x == 0) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(x), "An integer cannot contain zero digits.");

    try
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(10, x) -1);
    }
    catch 
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException($"A number with {x} digits cannot be represented as an integer.");
    }
}
```

If anyone can help with generating the **min** value or suggest improvements on the code above I'd appreciate it.

**Edit**

I'm almost there - this seems to work for everything except when `x` = 1 (and min value expected as 0)

```
public static int MinIntWithXDigits(this int x)
{
    if (x == 0) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(x), "An integer cannot contain zero digits.");

    x -= 1;

    try
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(10, x));
    }
    catch
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException($"A number with {x} digits cannot be represented as an integer.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is too broad. What _specifically_ are you having trouble figuring out? Does it occur to you that the _minimum_ value for a given number of digits is the same as the _maximum_ value for one fewer digits, plus one?

Comment: Its dumb, but it works: `parseInt(x > 1 ? "1" + "0".repeat(x-1) : "0")`

Comment: Your question is inconsistent with its use of `0` in the first group, but `1` as the starting number in the others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fox any x>1, the min value would be 10<sup>x-1</sup>. E.g.:

- If x = 2, min=10<sup>2-1</sup> = 10<sup>1</sup> = 10
- If x = 3, min=10<sup>3-1</sup> = 10<sup>2</sup> = 100
- If x = 4, min=10<sup>4-1</sup> = 10<sup>3</sup> = 1000

For x=1, since it's the only value that is not a one followed by a series of zeroes, you'll need special treatment.

```
public static int MinIntWithXDigits(this int x)
{
    if (x == 0) 
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(nameof(x), "An integer cannot contain zero digits.");
    }

    if (x == 1) {
        return 0;
    }

    try
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(10, x - 1));
    }
    catch 
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException($"A number with {x} digits cannot be represented as an integer.");
    }
}
```

Side note:
If the result were restricted to **positive** integers instead of **non-negative** integers, the smallest integer with one digit would be 1, and the general formula would have applied for this case too.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
// let's return min and max in one go as a value tuple
public static (int min, int max) MaxIntWithXDigits(this int x) {
  if (x <= 0 || x > 9)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(x));

  int min = (int)Math.Pow(10, x - 1); 

  return (min == 1 ? 0 : min, min * 10 - 1); 
}
```

Demo:

```
var result = Enumerable
  .Range(1, 9)
  .Select(x => $"{x} : {MaxIntWithXDigits(x).min} .. {MaxIntWithXDigits(x).max}"); 

Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

Outcome:

```
 1 : 0 .. 9
 2 : 10 .. 99
 3 : 100 .. 999
 4 : 1000 .. 9999
 5 : 10000 .. 99999
 6 : 100000 .. 999999
 7 : 1000000 .. 9999999
 8 : 10000000 .. 99999999
 9 : 100000000 .. 999999999
```